# Optimal filtering based on conditional multiple column criteria

Tags: sql, filtering, query-optimization, teradata

I need to filter a query based on conditional criteria. It seems straightforward, **I'm just looking for ideas to optimize the query**

I need to filter prices based on season, country and product. So the query would work more or less like:

```
    SELECT Country, Season, Product, Price
FROM Table
WHERE (Country = 'UK' AND Season = 'High' AND Product = 'X' AND Price < 30)
OR
(Country = 'ES' AND Season = 'Low' AND Product = 'Y' AND Price < 25)
OR 
(Country = 'FR' AND Season = 'Mid' AND Product = 'Z' AND Price < 50)
```

And so on. The problem is that the amount of combinations is huge and will make this impractical. Any ideas are welcome

Comment: If the number of filter combinations is huge, can you store them in another table? In that case a simple join will do the trick.

Comment: Good point. In my case it wouldn't be simple but all things considered it might be the best solution

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your `AND`ed expression have the same columns, then most databases would handle your query well.  They would use an index on (`Country, Season, Product, Price)`.

If you have such an index and there are no overlapping conditions, you can also phrase the logic as:

```
SELECT Country, Season, Product, Price
FROM Table
WHERE Country = 'UK' AND Season = 'High' AND Product = 'X' AND Price < 30
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, Season, Product, Price
FROM Table
WHERE Country = 'ES' AND Season = 'Low' AND Product = 'Y' AND Price < 25
UNION ALL
. . .
```

This is more flexible.  In case not all the conditions are exactly the same, this could still use indexes for the query.

You can also phrase this using `JOIN`.  Within the query, you can create a derived table:

```
SELECT Country, Season, Product, Price
FROM (VALUES ('UK', 'High', 'X', 20),
             ('ES', 'LOW', 'Y', 25),
             . . . 
     ) v(Country, Season, Product, Price) JOIN
     Table t
     ON t.country = v.country AND
        t.season = v.season AND
        t.product = v.product AND
        t.price < v.price;
```

You want the same (or similar) index for this query.

And, of course, you can store the values in a separate table.

Comment: I think it will do much better without the ORs. Will try it and see how it performs. Thank you